# hide a picture in phone

Tags: html, css

i want to hide a picture in the mobile.

what i did is:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .kredit1 {
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
    }    
</style>
```

and i putted this class in to this div:

```
<div class="" style="float: right;">
    <img src="_assets/_img/AAbisnode.png" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

but the webpage turned to just blank when i did this.

Comment: you didnot added any class in the html div.. see your code

Comment: there is no element with class `kredit1` ... (Also, the width rule is obsolete if you're using `display:none` )

Comment: for big screen also it changed blank right

Comment: Not sure why it would make the page go blank, but 1) You haven't assigned the class in your HTML anywhere, 2) I'm fairly certain that will ONLY display on mobile, not be hidden in mobile, and 3) Why do you have a width attribute in the CSS part?

Comment: In addition.. if it's not displaying, what's the width property for?

Answer (score 1):

Your class tag is empty in your div. Try this:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .kredit1 {
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
    }    
</style>


<div class="kredit1" style="float: right;">
    <img src="_assets/_img/AAbisnode.png" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "@media screen and (max-width: 600px)" to hide the image. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` to hide the image

```css
.kredit1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .kredit1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>
and i putted this class in to this div:

<div class="kredit1 " style="float: right;">

  <img src="_assets/_img/AAbisnode.png" style="width: 100%;">


</div>
```